# Android java socket read return eof, even on reconnect

Tags: android, sockets, eof, reconnect

java tcp client socket input read() returns -1. If return -1, reconnect again.
Reconnection succeeded, but -1 is returned again. and Send keepAlive to server every 10 seconds
I terminate the program and connect again, the connection is succeed and data is received.
I can't figure out the cause.

I would appreciate it if you could send me a reply on this matter.

```
private class SocketThread extends Thread{
        private Socket mSocket = null;
        private InputStream mInStream = null;
        private OutputStream mOutStream = null;

        public SocketThread(){

        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(mHostAddr);

                mSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, mHostPort);
                mInStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
                mOutStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
                mSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "connection error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();

                mState = STATE_NONE;
                mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_STATE_CHANGE, mState, -1).sendToTarget();
                return;
            }

            mState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_STATE_CHANGE, mState, -1).sendToTarget();

            while(true){
                try{
                    bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);

                    if(bytes >= 0) {
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    } else if (bytes == -1) {
                        this.cancel();
                        throw new SocketTimeoutException();
                    }

                    sleep(10);
                }
                catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                    Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "disconnected 3", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_RECONNECT, mState, -1).sendToTarget();
                    break;
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mState = STATE_NONE;
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_STATE_CHANGE, mState, -1).sendToTarget();
                    break;
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "disconnected 2", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mState = STATE_NONE;
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SOCKET_STATE_CHANGE, mState, -1).sendToTarget();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

```
    public void cancel(){
        if(mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        try{
            mInStream.close();
            mOutStream.close();
            mSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "close failed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
    case TCPClient.SOCKET_RECONNECT:
                    connect(true);
                    break;
```

```
public void connect(boolean connect)
    {
        if (connect)
        {
            if (mRelaySock.getStatus() == TCPClient.STATE_CONNECTED)
            {
                mRelaySock.stop();
            }
            mRelaySock.setHostInfo(mHostAddr, mHostPort);
            mRelaySock.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mRelaySock.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `InputStream.read()` returning -1 means end of stream. The peer has closed the connection. This has nothing to do with read timeouts whatsoever, and you are wrong to so treat it.  And it can never return zero unless your buffer is zero length or you supply a zero length. If you are getting constant end-of-streams, the server is constantly closing the connection on you. Investigate that.